# What's the rightway to use attached properties,signals?

Tags: qt, qml

I found some code use `Attached Properties,` in a strange way.
**case 1**

```js
Flickable {
    // ...
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```

**case 2**

```js
ListView {
    model: 3
    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "yellow"
    }
}
```

**case 3 or case 4...n**

```js
Item {
    Component.onCompleted: {
          console.log("hello")
        }
}
```

I am confused on `Attached Signals,Properties`, don't know what's time `Attached Signals,Properties` can use(call) somewhere in my code and don't knonw what it real means and real usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers) is very clear:

> Attached properties and attached signal handlers are mechanisms that
> enable objects to be annotated with extra properties or signal
> handlers that are otherwise unavailable to the object. In particular,
> they allow objects to access properties or signals that are
> specifically relevant to the individual object.
>
> A QML type implementation may choose to create an attaching type in
> C++ with particular properties and signals. Instances of this type can
> then be created and attached to specific objects at run time, allowing
> those objects to access the properties and signals of the attaching
> type. These are accessed by prefixing the properties and respective
> signal handlers with the name of the attaching type.
>
> References to attached properties and handlers take the following
> syntax form:
>
> ```
> <AttachingType>.<propertyName>
> <AttachingType>.on<SignalName>
> ```

In simple words, it allows adding new functionalities without modifying the base class.

In the first example it is observed that a ScrollIndicator is added (which is not necessarily part of the Flickable) without modifying the behavior of the Flickable.

In the second case, the "ListView" property that is not the ListView object is added to each delegate so that it can access information about the view. It should be remembered that the delegate has its own scope that is different from the view, for example you cannot access the delegate's properties outside of it.

And in the third case, the "Completed" object is added, which has the completed signal that is emitted when the base object(Item) finishes building.

Comment: The Qt offical document sometime is obscure for me,It's hard to understand what  they are talking about(sometime),emm my english is poor.